# Mass prefix and subfix

Tags: html, prefix

Input data:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Etc...
```

I want a output like this. Would prefer a .txt file

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/Text 1">Text 1</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/Text 2">Text 2</a>
```

Prefix is:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/"></a>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework ?

Comment: Dont know what it is but i dont think so.

Comment: You will have to write some code in javascript to get this done. Have a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). Then you'll have to do DOM updates. Have a look here as well https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: Explain what is the inputs, the context and the goal Do you want to transform txt into html?

Comment: Well ''Text 1'' and ''Text 2'' is in a notepad. I want to paste it somewhere and get the output as in the post #1. To make it more simple think u have a text file with a lot of rows and you want to add alot of prefixes and subfixes in the right place. This is what i want to do.

Comment: «paste it somewhere»? is your question about programming? do you imagine there is a "string" converter somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you comment, you need to learn about scripting...

e.g. with python you can do:

```
#!python3
inputext = """Text 1
Text 2
Etc..."""

outputext = ''
for line in inputext.split('\n'):
    outputext += "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.website.com/" + line + "\">" + line + "</a>\n"
with open('outfilepath.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(outputext)
```

Comment: Mm downloaded Python and i understand the flow in the code.
Dont really know if the code works or not but where does the output go?
Where is it printed?

Comment: I have tryied your code and it does what it needs to.
Can you make so instead of direct print it writes everything to a file?

Comment: Welcome in programming languages... you really should learn scripting for this kind of task. SO is not a 'code on demand' service. (note: I edited my answer)

Comment: python text.py > text.txt

Answer (score 0):

Made a .bat file (.py needs to be in same directory)

```
python text.py > text.txt
```